# Scrapy Update response HTML body

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

Is it possible to write the URL of a page I have just crawled inside a meta tag of a HTML response.body?  I need to add the meta tag below inside the response.body before saving it to a file. I do not need to extract a HTML tag.  I have the Xpath of the HTML head tag /html/head and I just need to add the meta data below to it.

```
class MSDSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "msdtest"
allowed_domains = ['workandincome.govt.nz']
start_urls = ['https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/map/definitions/alternative-housing.html',]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.html')), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
)

def parse_item(self, response):

    hxs = Selector(response)


    page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
    filename = '%s' % page

        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Is there an API or documentation on Scrapy that has an example on how to add to the response.body?

Comment: I don't think so, I think you should use html parser like `lxml` or `bs4` to add tag to the response and write it to file

Comment: Thanks I found a workaround.  I just replaced the response body with another body.  Like:  body = response.body
        new_body = body.replace('</title>', '</title><meta content="%s" name="url">' % response.url)
        page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        filename = '%s' % page
              
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(new_body)
                self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)